# On Android Activity Titlebar. Icon is clickable. I want turn it off

Tags: android, android-layout

I am developing android app with `android:Theme.Light`.

On any activity there is a app icon on left top of screen (see below screen) and by default it is clickable

I want to turn it off to not tappable or clickable.

[image]

Comment: which icon? where it is?

Comment: this icon http://screencast.com/t/l4WdiRdR

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to disable the home button on `ActionBar`, do this in `OnCreate`

```
ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
```